# Timeout problems processing large remote files

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm having problems with a script I need to collect information from a remote API my script works fine when working for only a few rows of data say 200 rows but as soon as I try to run larger datasets the page eventually shows a timeout message when I look at my logs the only useful thigg it says is the error code of 500.

I've tried increasing the memory limit, execution time and input time to see if this would solve the problem but so far it hasn't I've posted my script below, if anyone can see anything I've done wrong or a way to process large files remotely I'd be very grateful.

```
<?php
set_time_limit (0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
ini_set('max_execution_time','999');
ini_set('max_input_time','999');

load site settings
require_once ('config.php');

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pr']);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."pings WHERE holderID='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
while(false !== ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))) { 


   $response = file_get_contents("https://secure.comcetera.com/npl?user=".PINGUSERNAME."&pass=".PINGPASSWORD."&apiver=2.3&msisdn=".$r['r1']);      
   $data = split("\n",$response);

    if ($data[0]=="QUERYOK")
    {
        list($number,$network, $msg)=split(" ",$data[1]);
        if($msg ==''){$msg='OK';}
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT network FROM ".PREFIX."networks WHERE code='".$network."'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
        mysql_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."pings SET response='$msg', network='$row->network', dateUpdated='$dateandtime' WHERE r1='".$r['r1']."' ");
        //echo "Carrier for $number is $r->network";
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."pings SET response='".$data[0]."', dateUpdated='$dateandtime' WHERE r1='".$r['r1']."' ");
    }

}
mysql_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."pings_holder SET pinged='Yes' WHERE holderID  ='$id' ");
$_SESSION['success'] = 'Records Pinged '.$error;

header('Location: '.DIR);
exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you increase the maximum execution time? A 500 error should always come with a detailed error message in the logs. What does it say?

Comment: `set_time_limit` has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode if....

Comment: here's what is says in the error log [26/Oct/2011:11:29:30 +0000] "GET /pingcenter/includes/ping.php?pr=12 HTTP/1.1" 500 100 "https://www.theonepoint.org/pingcenter/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"

I'm sure the server is not running in safe mode

Comment: Are you sure that is the error log? That looks more like the access log to me. The error log should contain an actual error message explaining what happened

Comment: If was the access log my mistake the error log only had errors relating to other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to execute such a script as a separate process, with client only initiating the process. What if the client will close the browser without waiting?
It seems your script only updates database entries and reports it's done, so there are no API calls results sent to client and you could just trigger your processing script

```
exec("php pingRecords.php > /dev/null &");
```

and report it has started to the client.

You'd better also parallelize the API calls by using curl_multi functions. Curl also seems to have significantly better performance, see "[file_get_contents VS CURL, what has better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance)"

Comment: Ended up going down the exec route works perfectly this way I alert the client the process has started and when the process has ended, frees up the browser too.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to run the script through command line, this is often better for scripts processing a lot of data.

You'd need to make sure your FTP user has shell access, and then use something like [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to execute the php script on your server.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to do it that way but for my client needs to be able to initiate the process, so I've put together a Ui together everything works except reading large data, I'm thinking if I broke the reading into chunks that would be a better way maybe.

Comment: ah okay. Perhaps breaking it into chunks is the best way.

Either that or you set up a cron job to run every 5mins or something, check if the client has run the script (e.g. a flag in the database?), if it has then run the process, if it hasn't do nothing.